# How to force Glue to create smaller files in S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that runs for ~15 minutes and outputs around 75 1.5Gb files in CSV. I see a lot of resources online about reducing the number of files and increasing the file size.

Instead, I want to have more files that are smaller in size. I want to force Glue to create <=125Mb output files. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: Use those same resources, just set the number of lines lower rather than higher (or the number of files higher rather than lower).

Comment: The resources are referring to coalesce(). Based on my reading, coalesce() can reduce the number of partitions (not increase) without a full reshuffle of the data.

Comment: you are looking for `repartition`